# Mention of any Prophet in other holy books

Tags: tanach, nevua-prophecy

Did any prophet announce the mission of a future prophet, providing signs by which he would be known to be a prophet?

Did any prophet confirm that any prior prophets were in fact true prophets?

If the mission of a prophet was announced by a prior prophet, what are the references of this claim in the Torah and other holy books?

Comment: Hi saber tabatabaee yazdi and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Per [our site policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/828/759) questions about other religions are off-topic here as we can only be expected to be knowledgeable in Judaism. As such I have edited your answer to remove the parts that fall in that category. That said, I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: Hi @DoubleAA. thanks a lot. I'm very curious about all religions. please help me to ask my questions. thanks in advanced.

Comment: What do you mean by "announce the mission of"? And by "confirm the prior prophets"?

Comment: in our studies in school, teach us : all prophets sent by one GOD. and all of them have one message:"* God is 1.*". and any prophet speak about sign of future prophets. like What is his ethnicity? his race. Specific indicators. Height and shape and parents name to know him. alias name.

Comment: I think that there would be some difference between what you were taught and the conception of prophets within Jewish texts. You might want to review this first http://www.jewfaq.org/prophet.htm

Comment: Hi thanks a lot @Dan . exactly . some difference. Why am i here? because detect them and think more about them. that website is not open in our country! please summarize that for me,here, if possible for you. thanks in advance

Comment: I'll quote one paragraph "A prophet is basically a spokesman for G-d, a person chosen by G-d to speak to people on G-d's behalf and convey a message or teaching. Prophets were role models of holiness, scholarship and closeness to G-d. They set the standards for the entire community." The message is often repentance or warning, not simply "1 god".

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I hope you stick around and enjoy the site (and that it doesn't become banned in your country).  So by "predict" do you mean "give signs by which we'll know a future prophet is really a prophet" and by "confirm" do you mean "verify that a previous prophet was in fact a true prophet"?

Comment: hello . Thanks. yes exactly. @MonicaCellio

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi could your question be phrased as "how is a prophet identified according to Judaism?"

Comment: so so. But im seeking for documents about it

Comment: when we were a student at school, they thought us : all prophets have been sent by one GOD. and all of them have one message:"* God is 1 and only one.*" and each prophet tells his followers about the sign of the next prophets, for example his ethnicity, his race, Specific indicators like Height and shape and parents name, so he could be recognized.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi, I assume you didn't go to a Jewish school, then.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26350

Answer (score 4):

Eliyahu is told by Hashem to anoint Elisha to be his successor as a prophet ([Kings 1:19:16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.19.16?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)).

Yesha'ayahu ([8:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.8.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) prophesied of two future prophets: Zechariah ben Yevarchiyahu and Uriah Hakohen. Zechariah lived centuries later, in the beginning of the Second Temple era, but Uriah might have already been alive at the time - his prophecy was brought in the Book of Micha 3:12, according to the Talmud in [Makot 24b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Micah.3.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Makkot.24b.4&lang2=bi) and Micha lived around the time of Yesha'ayahu and may have even been his student (he paraphrases him a number of times).

Yirmiyahu ([26:17-24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jeremiah.26.17-24?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)) mentions two past prophets: Micha (of the Book of Micha) and Uriyahu ben Shma'ayahu.

Malachi ([3:23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Malachi.3.23?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) foretells the return of Eliyahu. During this time, Eliyahu will reconcile parents with children and children with parents.

Comment: *Malachi foretells the coming of Eliyah the prophet

Comment: @DoubleAA what's the difference? (Eliyahu is called Eliyah in Malachi for the same reason that there aren't any "Yah-u" names in the other Second Temple Era books)

Comment: I'm not sure what if any is the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Rambam ([Yesodei Hatorah 10:5](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904996/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Ten.htm#v5)) writes:

> נָבִיא שֶׁהֵעִיד לוֹ נָבִיא אַחֵר שֶׁהוּא נָבִיא הֲרֵי הוּא בְּחֶזְקַת נָבִיא וְאֵין זֶה הַשֵּׁנִי צָרִיךְ חֲקִירָה. שֶׁהֲרֵי משֶׁה רַבֵּנוּ הֵעִיד לִיהוֹשֻׁעַ וְהֶאֱמִינוּ בּוֹ כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל קֹדֶם שֶׁיַּעֲשֶׂה אוֹת. וְכֵן לְדוֹרוֹת.
>
> When a prophet proclaims that another individual is [also] a prophet, we accept the latter as a prophet without requiring [any further] investigation. Thus, after Moses, our teacher, proclaimed that Joshua [was a prophet], all the Jews believed in him before he performed any wonders. The same holds true for subsequent generations.

So there's an example of a prophet announcing the mission of a future one, and without providing any signs.